# Laravel Project not working in XAMPP htdocs folder.What could be the reason of this?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, xampp

Error States:

The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

my project is in htdocs>laravel>project1>public>index.php

Comment: This could be a few issues. Does a simple index.html file work in the public folder? Otherwise,  check the file storage/logs/laravel.log for errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

any more details like installation etc?
how did you install the laravel project by php artisan command or by composer or by zip package? and why you want to run your laravel project with the xammp file structure.. you can simply write the "php artisan serve" in your command line.. also make sure the .env variables set properly.. also try to clear all cache browser and run following query and try again 
php artisan cache:clear

you need to know that the default port of laravel project is localhost:8000

Comment: i am very new with Laravel and don't know whether we can use laravel alone to do everything like database phpmyadmin etc.

Comment: Yes it's a full fledged robust web framework written in pure php. laravel alone can do everything to make any dynamic web project. but you need to learn command line utilities and please read the documentation.

Comment: A good place to start is Laravel documentation, not here. Search for Laravel  getting started tutorials etc. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

When you meet 500 error, it's usually permissions related problem. Set write permissions on a `storage` directory. For Linux:

sudo chmod -R 775 storage

If it didn't help, look into Laravel error log.